# Executor unable to pick postgres driver in Spark standalone cluster

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, playframework, apache-spark-standalone

I was submitting the play application to spark 2.1 standalone cluster . In play application postgres dependency is also added and application works on local spark libraries. But at run time on standalone cluster it gives me error :

```
o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 172.31.21.3, executor 1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I have placed following in spark-defaults.conf directory

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /home/ubuntu/downloads/postgres/postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar 
spark.driver.extraClassPath     /home/ubuntu/downloads/postgres/postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar
```

Still executors unable to pick the driver. 
Am i missing something? Need help . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

place postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar to your SPARK_DIRECTORY/jars folder and restart the spark cluster